# A result on closed neighbourhood finite coverings

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to do the following exercise:

**Suppose** $X$ is a topological space, and that $(A_{\lambda})_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is a neighbourhood-finite closed covering of $X$.

**Suppose** also that $x \in A_{\lambda_i}$ for $i=1,...,n$, and that $V_i$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $A_{\lambda_i}$ (that is, with respect to the relative topology).

**To show**: $x$ has an $X$-nhood $V$ such that $V \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i.$

**Note**: neighbourhood-finite means that each $x \in X$ has a nhood intersecting at most finitely many of the $A_{\lambda}$.

**My attempt**: I write $V_i = A_{\lambda_i} \cap U_i$ for $X$-open $U_i$. I exhaustively list those $(A_\lambda)$ containing $x$: $$A_{\lambda_1}, ..., A_{\lambda_n}, A_{\lambda_{n+1}},..., A_{\lambda_{n+m}}.$$

By nhood finiteness,

$$\bigcap_{\lambda \neq \lambda_1,...,\lambda_{n+m} } A_{\lambda}^c $$

is open (of course, this is not true in general!).

So therefore is

$$V:=  \left( \bigcap_{\lambda \neq \lambda_1,...,\lambda_{n+m} } A_{\lambda}^c \right) \cap \bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i.$$

Now $x \in V$ and $V$ is open. But it's not the case that $V \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$. I cannot exclude the sets $A_{\lambda_i}$ for $n<i \leq n+m$ in the first intersection above, however, because then I may exclude $x$ from $V$.

I am going in the right direction? I cannot see how to conclude.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that you cannot exclude the sets $A_{λ_i}$ for $n < i ≤ n + m$. And you cannot conclude since in this form the proposition is false. Just consider $\{[0, 1], [1, 2]\}$ as a covering of $[0, 2]$. You are given $[0, 1]$ as a neigborhood of $1$ in $[0, 1]$. There is no neighborhood of $1$ in $[0, 2]$ that is contained in $[0, 1]$.

It would work if you are given $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ such that $F := \{λ: U ∩ A_λ ≠ ∅\}$ is finite, and a set of $V_λ$s for each $λ ∈ F$.

Aside: When you write $\bigcap_{λ ≠ λ_1, …, λ_{n + m}} A_λ$, you probably meant the intersection of complements of those sets.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help. (Glad to know I wasn't being too stupid). And I did mean that, and corrected now.